# Task in vscode for two plattforms (avoiding copy & paste)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I use the [tasks in VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks), also I am jumping between Windows and Linux (WSL2), sometimes I need also apple (osx).

I created some tasks, where I choose between the different platforms (windows, linux, osx).

Here my `tasks.json` file:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Create Hello World File",
            "group": "none",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}\\dummy.txt'"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}/dummy.txt'"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}/dummy.txt'"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The command for **osx** and **linux** is often the same. How can I avoid copy & paste the command?

I tried:

```json
{
  "label": "Create Hello World File",
  "group": "none",
  "type": "shell",
  "windows": {
    "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}\\dummy.txt'"
  },
  ["linux", "osx"]: {
    "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}/dummy.txt'"
  }
}
```

Of course that is not valid json, but it was a try.

Comment: Why not have only one task "linux_osx" and choose this when either on osx or linux ?

Comment: `linux_osx` is not a valid element in the task-json context

Comment: I meant, create a "label" with value "linux_osx" with everything within this label the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a platform dependent directory separator you can use a command variable.

Use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable).

Use the variable

```
${command:extension.commandvariable.dirSep}
```

---

**Edit**

> Valid operating properties are windows for Windows, linux for Linux, and osx for macOS. **Properties defined in an operating system specific scope override properties defined in the task or global scope.**

If you want certain options for `[linux, osx]` and different for `[windows]` define the `[linux, osx]` version in the task and the `[windows]` in the OS specific scope

```json
{
  "label": "Create Hello World File",
  "group": "none",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}/dummy.txt'"
  "windows": {
    "command": "echo \"Hello World\" > '${workspaceFolder}\\dummy.txt'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, that solve just the path sep topics. Anyhow I have much more "complx tasks". Is there an option that osx and linux is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside, a `${pathSeparator}` variable to be used in launch or task configurations should be in v1.52 - it is in the Insiders' Build now.